# Has Stack Overflow thought about working with the Khan Academy?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange

I have recently become aware of Khan Academy and I am impressed by the educational videos and exercises they provide on numerous topics.

But sometimes people just get stuck and need help grasping a concept or mastering a technique. I have found stackoverflow.com to be very helpful for these kinds of things in the area of software development.

I am wonder if Stack Overflow has thought about working with the Khan Academy to extend the Khan Academy site using Stack Exchange?

Comment: Only if I get to embed Youtube video's here!

Comment: On a side note, "Wikiversity" for programming is quite sparse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this would be a very different view for stack exchange to take, and I kinda doubt it will work but here goes:

Basically, having a special Khan Academy/"student"* stack exchange would basically enable students to help students. I'm sure there'll be a few experts that browse it from time to time, but in short it could work as more of a peer to peer type of help. Some students are really good at math; most of the ones I've seen that are good, are also eager to help struggling students. And so on. Also, as @Ivo has pointed out, there will most likely be a few teachers that also want to contribute.

The only big problem I see is that the quality of answers may be substantially less because of fewer experts. But when you need help factoring what other people call a simple math problem, you'll take all the help you can get with the assignment being due the next day.

`*` where student is high school or (lower level) college students

Comment: Probably a better idea would be **not** to limit the scope of our sites, like Math, Physics and any other new site that will pop up. The While some questions might be basic, it takes a real expert to write an answer that laymen can actually understand. I can't read any Wikipedia article about advanced Math stuff, because they just throw formulas in your face without bothering to explain those anywhere...

Comment: @Ivo, but then those SEs will be flooded with basic questions, and some experts may get annoyed/leave.

Comment: You could say the same for SO where you have questions like: [What's the syntax for commenting out lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2449304/77595) As long as it's about one topic, I don't think this problem is as bad as everyone thinks. I'm not saying anything should go, but I do think there's room for more basic questions

Comment: @Ivo, yea you got a point there.

Answer (score 3):

Your title and body seem to be asking different things...

If you're asking for a new site, all Stack Exchange site proposals must go through [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

On the other hand, if you're asking for a special partnership, I'm not sure that would work out too well—Khan Academy is mostly focused on high school and college level curriculum, while the only sites we have in those areas are [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com), which really doesn't like too basic questions, [English](http://english.stackexchange.com) and [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com). Compared to the number of sites we have, it doesn't look like a good overlap. Stack Exchange has found that without an expert community, it's hard to keep from degenerating into a poor quality site.

Comment: Just because there's no site for really basic question, doesn't mean there's no audience for it (points @Khan Academy)

Comment: @Ivo Khan Academy is lecture based and staffed by one person. SE is a Q-A based and depends on the contributions of the community.

Comment: That's still not to say there aren't high school teachers or other people who do this stuff for a living and would love to share their knowledge with others. The level of a question is often not as important as you think